# Error while installing Activiti BPM Engine on Ubuntu - MySql

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, tomcat8, activiti, business-process-management

I am trying to install activiti engine in ubuntu 14 LTS and Tomcat & MySql. I haven't alterterd any settings so far it is the default war which I deployed in tomcat. How ever when I am trying to access activiti-explorer I am getting below error. It works perfectly fine in the local landscape with same configuration but when I try to deploy it in client landscape this is the error I am getting. Can any one please help with this?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'explorerApp': Scope 'session' is not active for the current   thread; 
consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? 
If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: 
In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1010)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody out looking there for answer, I got it resolved by replacing the Tomee Server to tomcat. It seems there are some version conflict with activiti latest version and Tomee Server latest version. It works properly with Tomcat 8.